# Add/modify bcc in Grails Email Plugin via metaClass

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to intercept and possibly modify all calls to `mailService.sendMail` to add/modify a `bcc` to emails going out. It is a temporary experiment so I want to avoid finding/changing all of the existing code if possible.

Example:

```
mailService.sendMail {
    to 'my_email@provider.com'
    //bcc may be present
    from 'admin@mysystem.com'
    subject 'Hello'
    body 'Just testing'
}
```

I'm able to intercept the calls easily enough with this created in Bootstrap:

```
mailService.metaClass.invokeMethod = {String name, args ->
    println "intercepting for ${name}..."
    def res = delegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(delegate, args)
    println "done intercepting"
}
```

I am at a complete loss as to how to actually modify the call to either add a bcc if none is present, or add an address to it if it does exist. The `args` parameter is the closure - I've looked at everything I can find on the topic and no joy.

This is running on Grails 1.3.7 (I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can always add a `bcc` irrespective of `bcc` being defined earlier, is by composing the original closure arg with a new one:

```
mailService.metaClass.invokeMethod = {String name, args ->

    if( name == 'sendMail' ) {

        def newArgs = args[0] >> { bcc 'hr@mysystem.com' }

        //or def newArgs = { bcc 'hr@mysystem.com' } << args[0]

        def res = delegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, newArgs)
                                    .invoke(delegate, newArgs)
    }
}
```

Assuming mail should be bcc'd and `bcc` list remains same, this way we do not have to keep track of supplied `bcc` list. Make sure name of method is always checked to be `sendMail` in order to avoid interception for other methods, although all methods will be intercepted in `mailService` bean they will be skipped for others but `sendMail`.

**UPDATE:**
Closure composition is available from Groovy 1.8 and I highly doubt Groovy 1.8 is available with Grails 1.3.7. In that case you can try the below approach otherwise:

```
mailService.metaClass.invokeMethod = {String name, args ->
    if(name == 'sendMail') {
        println "intercepting for ${name}..."

        def newClos = { cl -> 
            return {
                cl.delegate = delegate
                cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
                cl()

                //bcc
                bcc 'hr@mysystem.com'
            }
        }

        def newArgs = newClos args[0]
        def res = delegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, newArgs)
                                    .invoke(delegate, newArgs)
        println "done intercepting"
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `args[0]` is the closure sent to the `sendMail` method. I did try both ideas just to be sure - right shift gives error `No signature of method rightShift() is applicable for argument types: closure25…`.  Left shift sets off a chain of interceptions that lead to a stack overflow error. By the way, I didn't think of out until you mentioned it but it would be nice to actually be able to parse the closure and keep track of who people were trying to bcc to...

Comment: Have you implemented the IF statement as I have mentioned above? That IF block should avoid th stackoverflow error. Please go through the answer again.

Comment: @Kelly closure composition might not be working due to older version of Groovy we get with Grails 1.3.7. There is a work around for that. I can update it once I get access to my desk.

Comment: I think this brings me much closer.  Currently run as above I get the error `expecting '{' found 'args[0]'` at the line `def newArgs = newClos args[0]`  I'm currently tinkering with how to get the closures concatenated.  Thanks SO much for your help!

Comment: You can use as `newClos(args[0])` or `newClos.call(args[0])` or `newClos.doCall(args[0])`. I just used it as a method call removing braces.